# How to access File object from test assets in Android instrumentation tests?

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-assets, android-instrumentation

I would like to read `File` object somehow in Android instrumentation tests.

I'm trying to get it using `assets` folder located in `androidTest`

```
File("//android_asset/myFile.jpg")
```

Unfortunately I cannot get this file. Is anyone aware how to create such `File` object? It does not necessarily have to be located in `assets`

Comment: Did you solved the problem?

Answer (score 3):

If you need to copy a file in the device, in example for test a C++ library that require the path to a file instead a stream, you can copy manually in this way:

```java
    @Test
    public void checkFileWorkingTxt() throws IOException {
        String path = "filepath.txt";
        Context context = InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext();

        // Creation of local file.
        InputStream inputStream = context.getResources().getAssets().open(path);

        // Copy file to device root folder
        File f = new File(context.getExternalCacheDir() + path);
        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(f);
        FileUtils.copy(inputStream, outputStream);

        // Check that everything works with native function
        bool result = NativeLibrary.check_txt(f.getAbsolutePath());
        assertTrue(result);
    }
```

This may be not the best way but it works.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you have a file under `src/androidTest/assets/myasset.txt` you would access it like `InstrumentationRegistry.getContext().getResources().getAssets().open("myasset.txt");`

Comment: I want to have `File` not `InputStream`